# ML Pipeline on AWS SageMaker: How to create long-running query/preprocessing tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, aws-lambda, pipeline, amazon-sagemaker

I'm a software engineer transitioning toward machine learning engineering, but need some assistance.

I'm currently using AWS Lambda and Step Functions to run query and preprocessing jobs for my ML pipeline, but am restrained by Lambda's 15m runtime limitation.

We're a strictly AWS shop, so I'm kind of stuck with SageMaker and other AWS tools for the time being. Later on we'll consider experimenting with something like Kubeflow if it looks advantageous enough.

**My current process**

- I have my data scientists write python scripts (in a git repo) for the query and preprocessing steps of a model, and deploy them (via Terraform) as Lambda functions, then use Step Functions to sequence the ML Pipeline steps as a DAG (query -> preprocess -> train -> deploy)
- The Query lambda pulls data from our data warehouse (Redshift), and writes the unprocessed dataset to S3
- The Preprocessing lambda loads the unprocessed dataset from S3, manipulates it as needed, and writes it as training & validation datasets to a different S3 location
- The Train and Deploy tasks use the SageMaker python api to train and deploy the models as SageMaker Endpoints

Do I need to be using Glue and SageMaker Processing jobs? From what I can tell, Glue seems more targeted towards ETLs than for writing to S3, and SageMaker Processing jobs seem a bit more complex to deploy to than Lambda.

Comment: Which step or steps are running into the 15min timeout?  It is unclear which aspect you need help with.

Comment: @BillWeiner the query and preprocessing steps, which I'm currently using Lambda for.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution that just came out for long running actions in Redshift - Redshift Data API.  https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/announcing-data-api-for-amazon-redshift/

This allows Lambdas in a Step function to issue a set of SQL to Redshift and poll to see when the SQL is done.  Now the run time of your Lambda is only as long as it needed to launch the SQL.

As for the processing steps - I'd recommend doing as much of the processing inside of Redshift before unloading the data to S3 (I hope you are not pulling lots of data through a select statement).  This will be much faster than processing in Lambda and can benefit from Data API as well.  Now there will likely be some processing steps that you cannot do in Redshift and Lambda is a good option.  One additional benefit of UNLOAD is that you can set the output file size.  This way you can launch a Lambda per file of the output and then you have many, shorter running Lambdas.

You could attempt to break up the work and have many Lambdas running in series but processing large amounts of data at once is not a strength of Lambda. Being able to do this will depend on the data processing you are doing.

You could use Glue for this but this is likely complete overkill, a whole new service to learn, and since it is an EMR wrapper it can get costly.  To be honest Glue is not my favorite AWS service as it only does the most basic things easily and anything even slightly complex becomes a battle. So if this is a tool you know and like go for it.

Comment: These suggestions sound very promising, and I'll definitely be testing them out! Thank you!